# jQuery ui Dialog shows just one time

Tags: asp.net, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm developing an app with asp.net and jQuery and I have a strange problem, I have the div(used as dialog) and a button to show the dialog, the first time I call the dialog, it shows correctly, I close it but when I try to show for the second time the background grays but the dialog doesn't show (only in IE in firefox it works fine). Is there a way to fix this? Or maybe I'm doing somethign wrong.

```
<div id="divAuto">
....
</div>

<button id="openAuto">SHOW</button>
```

And here's the js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var dlg = $('#divAuto').dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, show: "fold", hide: "drop", width: "500", height: "370" });
        dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));

        $('#openAuto').click(function() {
            $("#divAuto").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

I'm using "appenTo" because I'm using asp.net buttons in the dialog and it's the "fix" to get the buttons to work.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Ariel

Comment: Where did you get that "fix" from and what is it supposed to fix? I have doubts about that use of `appendTo()`...

Comment: The "fix" is for asp.net, because I'm using asp.net buttons that won't work if I don't use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try initiating the dialog in the click event instead.

```
$("#divAuto").parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
$("#openAuto").click(function() {
            $("#divAuto").dialog({
                 width: "500",
                 height: "370",
                 modal: true,
                 close: function(event, ui) {
                         $(this).dialog("destroy");
                 }
            });
});
```